# How to modify rows of large table in the shortest time using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, html-table

I have two html tables with the same amount of rows in each. I would like table A rows to have the same height as table B ones.
I tried something like this :

```
$tableA.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
    $row = $tableB.find('tr.calendar_row:eq(' + i + ')');
    $(this).height($row.height());
});
```

It works quite well, but when my tables are big (+300 rows), this function takes up to 8 seconds.

Is there a way to improve performance ? For example, I tried to store `tableA` and `tableB` rows to vars, and iterate through those arrays, but then it seems I can't use jquery's `height()` function.

EDIT : Here's my two tables : I want my `tableA` rows to match with `tableB`

[image: Tables image]

Comment: Are the tables next to each other? (side-by-side)?  One way would be to have a *single* table with a 'gap' column and tweak the borders so that it looks like two separate tables.   Then each `tr` will always be the same height regardless of content.

Comment: I think problem of your code is in finding element by index (`:eq()`) that take long time. You can store height of rows in variable like `var height = $("tr.calendar_row").map(function(){
    return $(this).height();
}).get();` and use variable in loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using it right, but my tableA's rows does not seem to take tableB's rows height. In my each loop, I use height var like this : `$(this).height(height);`

Comment: Consider changing the table structure using a single table with a gap in the middle. It is faster, safier and easier. It will adapt table row height without need for js

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a single table, as I need tableA to stay fixed while tableB can ben scrolled horizontaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Mohammad I managed to get what I want !
Here's the code :

```
var height = $tableB.find('tr.calendar_row').map(function () { return $(this).height(); }).get();
$tableA.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
    $(this).height(height[i]);
});
```

With this method, execution time is about 0.5s

Thank everyone for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

try to put the tableB's rows in a var :

```
var rows = $tableB.find('tr.calendar_row');
$tableA.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
    $row = rows.eq(i);
    $(this).height($row.height());
});
```

Comment: It does not seems to work, I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: $row.height is not a function

Comment: Mea culpa, it does work ! It is slower than Mohammad's solution (about 4 seconds), but it might help someone who faces the same problem.